# QTableView: Selecting a cell with single click

Tags: python, python-2.7, pyqt, pyqt4, qtableview

I have re-implemented **mouseReleaseEvent** method in QTableView (PyQt4) to select the cell of the table with **single click** and it worked.

```
def mouseReleaseEvent(self, event):
    index = self.indexAt(event.pos())
    self.setCurrentIndex(index)
    self.edit(index)
    self.update()
```

Now the problem is that when I select the multiple cells in the view, it doesn't selects all the selected cells. It only selects the last cell in the selection.

I tried to solve this by trial and error method but couldn't solved.

[image: Reference]

Comment: What is your goal? Do you want what you select to be pasted later in the excel? Only one item can be editable

Comment: My goal is to select the multiple cells selected for copy, cut etc. with "single click selection."

Comment: What do you mean by "single click selection" ?, currently without your code one presses an item and then drag the mouse and select several rows and columns.

Comment: The code I pasted above is allowing me to select an item with single click instead of double click. But when I drag the mouse over the multiple items, mouse cursor moves on last item without selecting multiple items.

Comment: You want that when you click on an item it is editable and if you drag the mouse you select the items. Is that what you want? If so, is it necessary that when you drag the mouse the items are editable?

Comment: try removing: `self.setCurrentIndex(index)` and `self.update()`, With the above, the selected items should no longer be lost.

Comment: Yes....Exactly that want...

Comment: Have you tried what I told you?

Comment: I tried by removing self.setCurrentIndex(index) and self.update(), but I still I couldn't select multiple items. Basically I am trying to achieve the same Excel like behavior.

Comment: I get the following: https://imgur.com/a/zpvaSI2. You do not confuse the selection with the edition.

Comment: ohh!! Really?? But Why I am not getting?? You did it.

Comment: Show me your complete code, probably the error is in another side. https://imgur.com/a/Qtm5dVG

Comment: Since I am using the same code suggested by you to define QTableView, I have attached the image. I have also attached the image what I actually wanted to do. https://imgur.com/a/GUPnztF

Comment: share your code as text, not as an image, I think you know that you must provide a [mcve] if you want help.

Comment: code sample https://justpaste.it/654df

Comment: I get https://imgur.com/a/ge1Bc8f If the behavior is not the same, it is probably a bug, update your version of PyQt4.

Comment: Thanks for the help.

Comment: Sorry!!! for putting extra comment here. As per your previous suggestion I was trying to update PyQt 4.12.1. Since I couldn't get .exe file, I am not able to update it on my pc. I have already raised separate query but not getting anyone's reply. By the way thanks for giving your valuable time. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51906417/how-to-update-pyqt-4-11-4-to-pyqt-4-12-1

Comment: I have updated PyQt4 to PyQt5 & Python 2.7 to Python 3.5, but still I am not getting the required things. https://justpaste.it/654df